# How to find the first ancestor node whose tag is <tbody> with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, css-selectors, ancestor

Suppose the jQuery object is $obj,how to select the desired ancestor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`parents()`](http://docs.jquery.com/Traversing/parents) with the [`:first`](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/first) selector:

```
obj.parents("tbody:first");
```

Comment: I didn't know where is a .parents() call!